# How to export mysql table from the terminal

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to bypass the `-secure-file-priv option` that MySQL has enabled to export a table into a .csv file.

I've been running  `SELECT * FROM final_table INTO OUTFILE 'test.csv'      FIELDS ENCLOSED BY '"'  TERMINATED BY ';'  ESCAPED BY '"'  LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';` into the terminal, but it has been returning `The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement`

Previously, I bypassed this error when importing files by running `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` instead of `LOAD DATA INFILE` which had the same error and was wondering if there was a way to do it with exporting as well.

Thanks!

Comment: In windows, you can try mysqldump command.

Comment: I tried running it (I use a Mac) and saw that it was useful for backing up the database, but I can't seem to actually get a working csv file. It's pretty useful for backups though, so thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: UPDATE: I tried running mysqldump -u root -p -t -T'test' [database] [table] and got  `mysqldump: Got error: 1290: The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement when executing 'SELECT INTO OUTFILE'` so that's still a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question since I found a solution that might help out other people.

`mysql -u root -p [database] -e '[SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME]' > data_export.csv`

got me exactly what I needed without disabling `secure-file-priv`!